# simple replace encryption code not working

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, netbeans

The main task this code is supposed to do is once I press the button the code would turn every letter from the entered string to the key the user entered, each letter has it's own key... I know it's a HUGE code but it uses very simple commands but I don't know why it's not working

```
private class ReplaceEncBtnHandler implements ActionListener{
    public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String sentence;
                 String repKeyA; String repKeyB; String repKeyC; String repKeyD;
                 String repKeyE; String repKeyF; String repKeyG; String repKeyH;
                 String repKeyI; String repKeyJ; String repKeyK; String repKeyL;
                 String repKeyM; String repKeyN; String repKeyO; String repKeyP;
                 String repKeyQ; String repKeyR; String repKeyS; String repKeyT;
                 String repKeyU; String repKeyV; String repKeyW; String repKeyX;
                 String repKeyY; String repKeyZ;

                 sentence = replaceinputTxt.getText();
            try{
                  repKeyA = repKeyTxtA.getText(); repKeyB = repKeyTxtB.getText(); repKeyC = repKeyTxtC.getText();
                  repKeyD = repKeyTxtD.getText(); repKeyE = repKeyTxtE.getText(); repKeyF = repKeyTxtF.getText();
                  repKeyG = repKeyTxtG.getText(); repKeyH = repKeyTxtH.getText(); repKeyI = repKeyTxtI.getText();
                  repKeyJ = repKeyTxtJ.getText(); repKeyK = repKeyTxtK.getText(); repKeyL = repKeyTxtL.getText();
                  repKeyM = repKeyTxtM.getText(); repKeyN = repKeyTxtN.getText(); repKeyO = repKeyTxtO.getText();
                  repKeyP = repKeyTxtP.getText(); repKeyQ = repKeyTxtQ.getText(); repKeyR = repKeyTxtR.getText();
                  repKeyS = repKeyTxtS.getText(); repKeyT = repKeyTxtT.getText(); repKeyU = repKeyTxtU.getText();
                  repKeyV = repKeyTxtV.getText(); repKeyW = repKeyTxtW.getText(); repKeyX = repKeyTxtX.getText();
                  repKeyY = repKeyTxtY.getText(); repKeyZ = repKeyTxtZ.getText();

                  replaceoutputTxt.setText("");
                  if(repKeyA.isEmpty()||repKeyB.isEmpty()||repKeyC.isEmpty()||repKeyD.isEmpty()||repKeyE.isEmpty()||
                          repKeyF.isEmpty()||repKeyG.isEmpty()||repKeyH.isEmpty()||repKeyI.isEmpty()||repKeyJ.isEmpty()||
                          repKeyK.isEmpty()||repKeyL.isEmpty()||repKeyM.isEmpty()||repKeyN.isEmpty()||repKeyO.isEmpty()||
                          repKeyP.isEmpty()||repKeyQ.isEmpty()||repKeyR.isEmpty()||repKeyS.isEmpty()||repKeyT.isEmpty()||
                          repKeyU.isEmpty()||repKeyV.isEmpty()||repKeyW.isEmpty()||repKeyX.isEmpty()||repKeyY.isEmpty()||
                          repKeyZ.isEmpty()){
                      replaceoutputTxt.setForeground(Color.red);
                      replaceoutputTxt.setText("You must fill all key elements!");
                      repKeyTxtA.requestFocusInWindow();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      String[] chars = sentence.split("(?!^)");

                     for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
                     {
                         String c = chars[i];
                          String[] decrypted = replacecipher(c,repKeyA,repKeyB,repKeyC,repKeyD,
                         repKeyE, repKeyF,repKeyG,repKeyH,repKeyI,repKeyJ,repKeyK,repKeyL,
                         repKeyM,repKeyN,repKeyO,repKeyP,repKeyQ,repKeyR,repKeyS,repKeyT,
                         repKeyU,repKeyV,repKeyW,repKeyX,repKeyY,repKeyZ);
                          String output = Arrays.toString(decrypted);

                          replaceoutputTxt.append(output);
                     }
                 }
              }
            catch (Exception j)
            {
            }
    }     
}
public static String[] replacecipher(String c,String repKeyA,String repKeyB,String repKeyC,String repKeyD,
                         String repKeyE,String repKeyF,String repKeyG,String repKeyH,String repKeyI,
                         String repKeyJ,String repKeyK,String repKeyL,String repKeyM,String repKeyN,
                         String repKeyO,String repKeyP,String repKeyQ,String repKeyR,String repKeyS,
                         String repKeyT,String repKeyU,String repKeyV,String repKeyW,String repKeyX,
                         String repKeyY,String repKeyZ)
    {
        int i = 0;

        String letA = "a", letB = "b", letC = "c", letD = "d";
        String letE = "e", letF = "f", letG = "g", letH = "h";
        String letI = "i", letJ = "j", letK = "k", letL = "l";
        String letM = "m", letN = "n", letO = "o", letP = "p";
        String letQ = "q", letR = "r", letS = "s", letT = "t";
        String letU = "u", letV = "v", letW = "w", letX = "x";
        String letY = "y", letZ = "z";


        String[] out = c.split("(?!^)");
        while (i < 26)
        {
            if (out[i].equals(letA)){
                out[i]=repKeyA;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letB)){
                out[i]=repKeyB;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letC)){
                out[i]=repKeyC;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letD)){
                out[i]=repKeyD;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letE)){
                out[i]=repKeyE;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letF)){
                out[i]=repKeyF;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letG)){
                out[i]=repKeyG;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letH)){
                out[i]=repKeyH;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letI)){
                out[i]=repKeyI;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letJ)){
                out[i]=repKeyJ;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letK)){
                out[i]=repKeyK;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letL)){
                out[i]=repKeyL;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letM)){
                out[i]=repKeyM;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letN)){
                out[i]=repKeyN;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letO)){
                out[i]=repKeyO;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letP)){
                out[i]=repKeyP;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letQ)){
                out[i]=repKeyQ;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letR)){
                out[i]=repKeyR;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letS)){
                out[i]=repKeyS;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letT)){
                out[i]=repKeyT;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letU)){
                out[i]=repKeyU;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letV)){
                out[i]=repKeyV;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letW)){
                out[i]=repKeyW;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letX)){
                out[i]=repKeyX;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letY)){
                out[i]=repKeyY;
                i++;
            }
            else if(out[i].equals(letZ)){
                out[i]=repKeyZ;
                i++;
            }
            else{
            out[i]="";
            i++;}
        }
        return out;
    }
```

I would appreciate any help and I apologize for the bulkiness but when I work it's either a super simple Huge code OR an overly complicated small code. My brain is still processing how to do both. :)

Comment: At this point you should probably learn how to use arrays.